# Big Θ of 27^n? How is 9^n not the answer?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am unable to understand how the equation `27^n =  Θ(9^n)` is not true?
Won't `9^n` always be smaller than 27^n?

Comment: Big theta needs to be both an upper and lower bound (after multiplying by a constant) and here it's only a lower bound.

Comment: So you mean that `Ω(9^n)` would be true? @interjay

Comment: @AbdulWasey correct. For future reference, use the [limit definition of big-Theta](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Big-Theta).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for the clarification!